# JavaScript code not working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://codepen.io/abdulahhamzic/pen/xVMXQa

This is my project. I want to put the letters of userWord in the five boxes. Why does it happen with only every second letter when I use this JavaScript code?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
        document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input].childNodes[i].innerHTML = "<h1>" + userWord[i].toUpperCase() + "</h1>";
    }
```

I can't seem to figure out the solution. :)

Comment: The text inside the `<h1>` counts as a node in the `childNodes` list.

Comment: are you trying to make a game of hangman?

Comment: Not quite, the idea is a little different, but this is just the starting point in the making of the app. Although, I'm not pretty much a beginner in JavaScript. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `childNodes` property returns all the nodes within an element, and these include text nodes, the whitespace between the actual elements. Instead, try using `children`, which only returns child elements, which is what you want.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
    document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input].children[i].innerHTML = "<h1>" + userWord[i].toUpperCase() + "</h1>";
}
```

(I tested this in your CodePen, and it did exactly what you want.)

For more details see:

- MDN Docs: [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- MDN Docs: [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the difference between children and childNodes. I see now. Thanks!

Comment: @АбдулахХамзиќ Anytime! It'd be great if you could mark my submission as the answer. :)

Comment: Yeah, sure! I didn't even know there was an option like that :)

Answer (score 2):

That would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("letter")[i].firstElementChild.textContent = userWord[i].toUpperCase();
}
```

or

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".letters > .letter"), 0, 5).forEach(function (node, index) {
    node.textContent = userWord[index].toUpperCase();
});
```

Documentation:

- [ParentNode.firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

ChildNodes is grabbing text, what you want is .children()

```
var word = 'МАЈКА';
var userWord;
var theNode;
var theClone;
var input = 0;
function game() {
        userWord = document.getElementById("text").value;
        theNode = document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input];
        theClone = theNode.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(theClone);
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
            document.getElementsByClassName("letters")[input].children[i].innerHTML = "<h1>" + userWord[i].toUpperCase() + "</h1>";
        }
        input++;
}
```

**WORKING DEMO!!**
http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/yOZwNP